# Determinate text position in a FPDF template

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm noob in fpdf and I was wondering if there's a way to predetermine where to place a text in a document.

Ex.
I'd like to put a transaction date after a "Date" in a template.

What I'm doing now is using a script like this one

```
$nomeFile = date("YmdHis").".pdf";
$pathTmp = "path/to/template.pdf";
$pathTmp1 = "path/to/result.pdf";
$pdf = new Pdf($pathTmp);
$pdf = new TcpdfFpdi();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile($pathTmp);
$template = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($template);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->Text(78, 70, '1');
$pdf->Text(38, 78, '2');
$pdf->Text(45, 87, '3');
$pdf->Text(47, 113, '4');
$pdf->Text(65, 145, '5');
$pdf->Output($pathTmp1, "F");
```

So, basically, place random values and see which one is the nearest to my label, but this way is too time-wasting

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetY](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/gety.htm) function to find out where you are on the line then the [SetY](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/sety.htm) function to position the next bit of text.

You will probably find the [SetXY](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setxy.htm) function handy also for absolute positioning when neeeded.

Here's a snippet of code that creates an address block with appropriate offsets to keep everything lined up.

```
$ourpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
$to_offset = $ourpdf->GetStringWidth('To:') + 27;
$ourpdf->Cell(0,4,'To:',0,0);
$ourpdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,75);
$ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['name'],0,0);
$ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,79);
$ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['contact'],0,1);
$ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,83);
$ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['address1'],0,1);
```